# simple javascript replace function

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, error-handling

Does anyone know this issue about replace function of javascript ?
I only want to replace string.

```
"$$$AAA".replace("$$$AAA","$$$aaa");
```

Event using with regex it's getting same output.

```
"$$$AAA".replace(new RegExp(/\$\$\$AAA/, "gi"),"$$$aaa");
```

Output

`$$aa`

Expected

`$$$aaa`

It's strip out the first `$`

Comment: `$<char>` sometimes has a special meaning in the replacement string. Use `$$` instead, for a literal `$`

Comment: so i need to add extra `$` before the string that start with `$`. hmm. so it's the rule of js.